# Scala unexpected output for List.orElse

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I expect the following code output with `Seq(0)`, instead it returns a function ?

```
@ Seq(0).orElse(Seq(1))
res2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = <function1>
```

I suspected at first that via syntax sugar it `orElse` on `apply` function, but it didn't since by trying:

```
@ Seq(0).apply.orElse(Seq(1))
cmd3.sc:1: missing argument list for method apply in trait SeqLike
....(omit)
```

I checked in IntellJ that there's no `implicit conversion`.
What happens?

---

EDIT:
what I wish is:
`Seq.empty.orElse(Seq(1)) == Seq(1)`
`Seq(0).orElse(Seq(1)) == Seq(0)`

---

thanks @AndreyTyukin answer.
In one line, `orElse` has different semantic in different type , now `Seq` inherits `PartialFunction` not `Option`, so does the `orElse` behavior.

Comment: Apply has an mandatory argument that you missed, to use apply explicitly the index should be passed:
Seq.apply(0).orElse(Seq(1))

Comment: @AlexEvseenko That's the same as `Seq(0).orElse(Seq(1))`. If you meant `Seq(0).apply(0).orElse(Seq(1))`, then it's invalid, because `Int` has no method `orElse`.

Comment: I meant statement from the original post:

**@ Seq(0).apply.orElse(Seq(1))
cmd3.sc:1: missing argument list for method apply in trait SeqLike**

Comment: On EDIT: For this to be type-safe, the `PartialFunction` would have to be F-polymorphically bounded by the return type of the `orElse`-method. Given how deeply `PartialFunction` is embedded in the standard API and the compiler, this will probably never happen. If you don't need this type-safely, it would *theoretically* be possible to implement the `orElse` in this way, but it would be more of a hack... May I ask *why* you need this? Wouldn't your own "pimp-my-library"-pattern do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Seq(0)` is treated as a `PartialFunction`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) that is defined only at index `0`, and produces as result the constant value `0` if it is given the only valid input `0`.

When you invoke `orElse` with `Seq(1)`, a new partial function is constructed, that first tries to apply `Seq(0)`, and if it finds nothing in the domain of definition of `Seq(0)`, it falls back to `Seq(1)`. Since the domain of `Seq(1)` is the same as the domain of `Seq(0)` (namely just the `{0}`), the `orElse` does essentially nothing in this case, and returns a partial function equivalent to `Seq(0)`.

So, the result is again a partial function defined at `0` that gives `0` if it is passed the only valid input `0`.

---

Here is a non-degenerate example with sequences of different length, which hopefully makes it easier to understand what the `orElse` method is for:

```
val f = Seq(1,2,3).orElse(Seq(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
```

is a partial function:

```
f: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>
```

Here is how it maps values 0 to 4:

```
0 to 4 map f

// Output: Vector(1, 2, 3, 40, 50)
```

That is, it uses first three values from the first sequence, and falls back to the second sequence passed to `orElse` for inputs `3` and `4`.

---

This also works with arbitrary partial functions, not only sequences:

```
scala> val g = Seq(42,43,44).orElse[Int, Int]{ case n => n * n }
g: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>

scala> 0 to 10 map g
res7 = Vector(42, 43, 44, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

---

If you wanted to select between two sequences without treating them as partial functions, you might consider using

```
Option(Seq(0)).getOrElse(Seq(1))
```

This will return `Seq(0)`, if this is what you wanted.

Comment: I think the wording of the second sentence is misleading.  When `pfA.orElse(pfB)` is applied to `x`, `pfB` will only be invoked if `pfA` is undefined at `x`.  So, it is confusing to say that "you override the returned value" because there is no returned value—if there were, it would not be overridden.

Comment: @JoePallas You are right. This statement was just plain wrong. I updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: in console `Seq(0); res46: Seq[Int] = List(0)`
Seq(0) is List now ?

Comment: so that the type of Seq is dynamic between List and PartialFunction ?

Comment: @WeiChingLin It simply *extends* `PartialFunction`. Look up in the inheritance hierarchy for `Seq`: it's `Seq[A] extends PartialFunction[Int, A]`.

Comment: thankyou, I thought it would behave as Option. I should have first saw what it does from looking at type hierarchy.