# What is the idiomatic (and fast) way of treating the empty list/Seq as failure in a short-circuiting operation?

Tags: list, scala, monads, option-type

I have a situation where I am using functions to model rule applications, with each function returning the actions it would take when applied, or, if the rule cannot be applied, the empty list. I have a number of rules that I would like to try in sequence and short-circuit. In other languages I am used to, I would treat the empty sequence as false/None and chain them with `orElse`, like this:

```scala
def ruleOne(): Seq[Action] = ???
def ruleTwo(): Seq[Action] = ???
def ruleThree(): Seq[Action] = ???

def applyRules(): Seq[Action] = ruleOne().orElse(ruleTwo).orElse(ruleThree)
```

However, as I understand the situation, [this will not work  and will, in fact, do something other than what I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819087/scala-unexpected-output-for-list-orelse).

I could use `return` which feels bad to me, or, even worse, nested `if` statements. `if let` would have been great here, but AFAICT Scala does not have that.

What is the idiomatic approach here?

Comment: Write an extension method `ifNonEmpty` on `Seq[T]` and write `ruleOne().ifNonEmpty(ruleTwo).ifNonEmpty(ruleThree)`. See e.g. https://www.wix.engineering/post/scala-extension-methods-via-implicit-classes for Scala 2 and https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-extension-methods.html for Scala 3.

Comment: I would rather change the domain model to `Option[NonEmptyList[Action]]`

Comment: That's what I would have done if I'd known about `NonEmptyList`. Or is that just a cats thing? My whole reason for not going with `Option` is that it does not capture the fact that the list in the case of `Some` is never empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have different approaches here.
One of them is combining all the actions inside a Seq (so creating a `Seq[Seq[Action]]`) and then using `find` (it will return the first element that matches a given condition). So, for instance:

```
Seq(ruleOne, ruleTwo, ruleThree).find(_.nonEmpty).getOrElse(Seq.empty[Action])
```

I do not know clearly your domain application, but the last `getOrElse` allows to convert the `Option` produced by the `find` method in a `Seq`. This method though eval all the sequences (no short circuit).

Another approach consists in enriching `Seq` with a method that simulated your idea of `orElse` using pimp my library/extensions method:

```
implicit class RichSeq[T](left: Seq[T]) {
   def or(right: => Seq[T]): Seq[T] = if(left.isEmpty) { right } else { left }
}
```

The by name parameter enable short circuit evaluation. Indeed, the right sequence is computed *only if* the left sequence is empty.

Scala 3 has a better syntax to this kind of abstraction:

```
extension[T](left: Seq[T]){
  def or(rigth: => Seq[T]): Seq[T] = if(left.nonEmpty) { left } else { rigth }
}
```

In this way, you can call:

```
ruleOne or ruleTwo or ruleThree
```

[Scastie for scala 2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/3juMPTZySDmEnGYH2nWEeA/5)

[Scastie for scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/6VY8pbU5T3mKtZIdmabqgw/9)

Comment: Would the first ("Pimp My Library") approach evaluate the other functions ahead of time? Doing that is expensive and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not consider the short circuit thing. I update the question using by name parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out in the meantime, but it's always nice to know I didn't do something weird.